# Cleaning oscilloscope range switches

Tags: repair, best-practice

The various range switches on my oscilloscope obviously collected some dirt over the years. Sometimes the input attenuators show a frequency dependent response (just like poorly matched probe) and the timebase wiggles all over place. It is a fully analog scope and I have full service manuals.

I've seen spray cans used for cleaning these switches, are they any good for this kind of job (measurement equipment)? Are there particular types I should avoid? Are there particular techniques / best practices to clean these switches?

Comment: What kind of scope?  Have a photo of the switches from the inside? Old Tektronix used silver since silver oxide is a conductor. Relay and tuner cleaners that leave no residue should be OK

Comment: @C.TowneSpringer [Philips PM3209](http://www.radiomuseum.org/r/philips_oscilloscope_pm3209.html) I've been trying to find a PDF version of the datasheet online, but didn't find any. In the paper version there are no images either. It is a Philips budget scope, 40MHz dual time base.

Comment: The lazy man's solution is to just move the switches through their range a couple dozen times. Sometimes, this alone gets them "clean enough", without any need to open the case.

Comment: @PhilFrost yes that works for short period, but it is getting annoying lately. It is a perfectly good scope otherwise.

Comment: I believe from memory the switches are open multi-layer rotary switches. Not sure what the proper name is.

Answer (score 2):

Contact cleaner should work fine. Dave Jones on the EEVblog used it to clean the switches on an analog oscilloscope he got in an auction and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Won't dust / dirt build up more easily afterwards, because I guess that is what I'm most worried about at the moment.

Comment: No more so than it did before. You aren't actually breaking any hermetic seals to apply the cleaner.

Comment: If there were any hermetic seals I probably wouldn't have the issue in the first place ;o)

Comment: Any chance you can link to that video or post?